# Finding the remainder of $N= 10^{10}+10^{100}+10^{1000}+\cdots+10^{10000000}$ divided by $7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$$N= 10^{10}+10^{100}+10^{1000}+\cdots+10^{10000000}$$. What is the remainder when N is divided by 7?

$$N=(10^{10}+10^{100}+10^{1000}+\cdots+10^{10000000})/7$$

$$Rem[3^{10}+3^{100}+\cdots+3^{10000000}]/7$$

Now I did not understand it from the next step

Now in the next step it has been given

$Rem[3\cdot 3^9+3\cdot3^{99}+\cdots+3\cdot3^{9999999}]/7$

$Rem[\underbrace{(-3)+(-3)+\cdots(-3)}_{7~\text{times}}]/7$

Comment: you can use { and } after the ^ to get all the digits into your exponent

Comment: Typesetting note:  `$3^lotsofstuff$` appears as $3^lotsofstuff$, but `$3^{lotsofstuff}$` appears as $3^{lotsofstuff}$

Comment: It helps to recognize that $3^3=27=28-1=4\cdot 7 - 1\equiv -1\pmod{7}$ and further that $10^n\equiv 1\pmod{3}$ for all $n\geq 0$

Comment: I did not understand  @JMoravitz

Comment: It isn't clear whether you are having trouble with the step going from $3^{10}+3^{100}+\dots+3^{10000000}$ to $3\cdot 3^9+3\cdot 3^{99}+\dots$ as well.. but that follows from basic properties of exponents... that $3^{a+b}=3^a\cdot3^b$ where here $a=1$ and $b=99\dots9$.... that is to say $3^{10}=3\cdot 3^9$ and that $3^{100}=3\cdot 3^{99}$ etc...

Comment: @Sakuzi you did not understand the math in my first comment?  or you did not understand how and why what I mentioned in my first comment is useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3^9 is a multiple of 3^3 which can be written as 27 and what is 27=28-1 now if you divide 27 by 7 what is the remainder?. It is -1 so now you multiply it with 3 in every step

so= $-3 (7times )/7$

Comment: Thanks alot @James

Comment: It should be pointed out that $3^9$ being a multiple of $3^3$ isn't by itself a strong enough condition to imply anything.  What is important here is that $3^9$ is an *odd power* of $3^3$ (*as are all numbers of the form $3^{99\dots9}$*).  E.g. $54$ is a multiple of $3^3$ but is equivalent to $5\pmod{7}$, not $-1$.

Comment: sorry but I meant to say the same will edit my answer or you should edit it

Answer (score 0):

Here I will use notation common for modular arithmetic.

Given $A$ and $a$ integers and $n$ a natural number different from $0$, the following are equivalent:

- $(A-a)$ is a multiple of $n$
- $(a-A)$ is a multiple of $n$
- $n$ divides evenly into $(A-a)$
- the remainder of $(A-a)$ when divided by $n$ is zero
- $A-a\equiv 0\pmod{n}$
- $A\equiv a\pmod{n}$
- There exists some integer $k$ such that $A-a=k\cdot n$

---

Some basic properties of modular arithmetic:

If $A\equiv a\pmod{n}$ and $B\equiv b\pmod{n}$ then the following are true:

- $A+B\equiv a+b\pmod{n}$
- $A\cdot B\equiv a\cdot b\pmod{n}$
- $A^k\equiv a^k\pmod{n}$

That is to say, we can replace summands or multiplicands with things which are modularly equivalent to them as we wish.

**Note:** The following is **not** true in general: $A^B\equiv A^b\pmod{n}$.  Exponents follow different rules and cannot be replaced with things they are equialent to modulo $n$, but could be replaced by something else if you are careful and spot the appropriate pattern.  See for example Fermat's Little Theorem.

---

Now, back to your problem, we notice first that $3^3=27=28=4\cdot 7-1$.  We try to rewrite this in a convenient fashion for use in modular arithmetic.  Well... $7\equiv 0\pmod{7}$ so...

$3^3\equiv 4\cdot \color{red}{7}-1\equiv 4\cdot \color{red}{0}-1\equiv 0-1\equiv -1\pmod{7}$ where here we replaced $7$ with $0$ since they are equivalent modulo $7$ and we made normal arithemtical simplifications.

Further, we notice by looking at powers of $3^3$ that:

$3^{99\dots 9}\equiv (3^3)^{33\dots3}\equiv (3^3)^{\text{some even number}}\cdot (3^3)\equiv (-1)^{\text{some even number}}\cdot (-1)\pmod{7}$

Here, we used the property that we can replace bases of exponents with something they are equivalent to modulo $7$.  Noticing further that $(-1)$ to an even power is just $1$ we can simplify further.

This tells us that $3^{99\dots 9}\equiv -1\pmod{7}$ for any number of the form $99\dots9$ regardless the length.  (*It could be more rigorous, if you need I'll provide full details but I expect this is fine.*)

Now, notice that by basic properties of exponents we have $3^{10^n}=3\cdot 3^{10^n-1}$ is of the form $3\cdot 3^{99\dots 9}$ for any $n\geq 1$ so we have:

$3^{10}+3^{100}+3^{1000}+\dots \equiv 3\cdot 3^{9}+3\cdot 3^{99}+3\cdot 3^{999}+\dots$

$\equiv 3\cdot (-1)+3\cdot (-1)+3\cdot (-1)+\dots\pmod{7}$

Again using the fact that we can replace multiplicands with something they are equivalent to.  Now, we make normal arithmetic simplifications:

$\equiv 7\cdot (3\cdot (-1))\equiv 0\cdot (3\cdot (-1))\equiv 0\pmod{7}$